# Install Oracle Apex 19.2

Tags: oracle

I need to upgrade my current oracle apex (19.1) on database 11gr2 to latest version 19.2. while I'm running @apxrtins.sql SYSAUX SYSAUX TEMP /i/ command this error message has been raised "ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20001: Install errors found in phase 1, see "not ok" messages above for
details.
ORA-06512: at "APEX_190200.WWV_INSTALL_API", line 440
ORA-06512: at line 5"

[image]

Comment: If you do: select * from v$version what *particular* version of 11.2 do you have? I just tried an install onto 11.2.0.4 EE, and did not see this error.

Answer (score 1):

OPEN_CONNECTION sounds a lot like a call to UTL_SMTP to me.

But I've just done a 19.2 installation into:

11.2.0.4 EE
11.2.0.4 SE
11.2.0.5 XE

and all of them installed without incident,

Comment: what you mean "OPEN_CONNECTION " ?

Comment: the error line 1902/13 says invalid usage of open_connection

Answer (score 1):

You've tried to upgrade your APEX with Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0. Oracle Application Express release 19.1 and above requires an Oracle Database release 11.2.0.4 or later, including Enterprise Edition and Express Edition (Oracle Database XE).